# Equivlent of coocon gem in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I recently switched over from rails to grails and was wondering if there is an equivalent of the coocon in somesort of plugin for grails. If your unfamiliar with the coocon gem it allows to dynamically add fields. If not what is the best why to dynamically add form fields in grails?

Comment: You might want to look into this plugin, it's old but it's the only thing I've ever seen that is remotely like what you are looking for: https://grails.org/plugin/dynamic-domain-properties

Comment: I took a look and it is not supported in grails 3 unfortunately . I need to dynamically add a select box populated with objects, I know to populate late the select box with object but not sure how to go about adding a new one dynamically. Any ideas?